# Android facebook applicationId cannot be null error despite correct app_id

Tags: android, android-facebook

I know this question has been asked before, but my problem is that I have set up the Manifest and Strings files correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hellofb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.hellofb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.hellofb.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.hellofb.LoginActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

(app_id string edited for security)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Hello FB</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="app_id">18031830547XXXX</string>

</resources>
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong? Have I by any chance set things up the wrong way? Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It should be like below:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

You should not alter the name string.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! So I guess this value is being set for the SDK library rather than the current project.

Comment: Yes exactly. Facebook SDK is getting the application id from this meta. So the name should not be changed.

Comment: Thank you. You have delivered me from a day-long headache. :)